# RMonkey: Can't integrate survey data from SurveyMonkey to R, can't get OAuth 2.0

Tags: r, surveymonkey

I want to connect the survey responses from my SurveyMonkey survey to R so that these can be analysed in real time as they come in for an RShiny dashboard.

I've loaded the Rmonkey package, and I've created a private app through SurveyMonkey and derived the SurveyMonkey username, password, client ID, SurveyMonkey secret, access token and the OAuth Redirect URL. Below is my code

```
options(sm_api_key = 'xxxxx')
options(sm_secret = 'yyyy')
options(sm_client_id = 'zzzz')
smlogin()
```

After running that, we are directed to a web browser and get the following error message: "Survey Monkey The authorization request failed: API key is not required for this app."

We have been using this document for help (https://github.com/cloudyr/Rmonkey) but are concerned that it is from 2016 and thus may be outdated. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!